# UltraEdit Java Editor Setup

Tags: java, editor, ultraedit

Does anyone have some suggestions on how to set up UltraEdit-32 (I'm using version 8.10a) for use as a Java editor?

Specifically, I'd like to have the ability to auto-format source code based on a coding style that can be configured.

For example, if I place an open brace at the end of a method definition (same line) and hit return, I'd like the editor to indent to the next line 4 spaces.

If UltraEdit isn't a good tool for this, can someone suggest a better editor?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netbeans or Eclipse are good ones. UltraEdit , TextPad or EditPlus are good too, but not so well equipped with respect to automatic suggestions and formatting as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

UltraEdit is not a good choice if you plan on doing any serious development work. Consider using Eclipse, which is open source.

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/heliosr